# Odoo 8 - add event handler on input text in javascript

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo-8, odoo

is there a way to add an event handler which handles an onchange event on input text. I need to put constraint on the invoice line where the user shouldn't fill a quantity greater than the value in the text box.

```
<field name="quantity" event="onchange(this)"/>

onchange(){
console.log..
}
```

10x

Answer (score 0):

For your task you don't need to use js, use python code for this, you can use `@api.onchange` and throw warnings or you can also create db constrains from there. db constrains works only when saving while `@api.onchange` works during editing

And if you still want to use js and cause headaches you can use jQuery to set onchange on any fields like this

```
$(SELECTOR).change(function (e) {});
```

Comment: the @api.onchange in my case (Wizard) didn't work. I couldn't fetch the original value of the field in the line within the tree . I'm checking the widget.